# Issue with combination of css 'transform' and 'z-index' in Safari

Tags: css, slider, transform, z-index

I've faced with an issue in slider. 
Slider itself is a modal window with images container inside (3 img - previous, current and next in stack). Transition to next/previous image supported by animation of `clip-path` property. Modal window is animated as well - rotating on X and Y axes with 1000px perspective on `mousemove`.

In Safari there is a problem when container is rotated : the 'top' image is cut, and the image, which is placed below is visible. It looks like this: 
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agfZ3.jpg)
I'm really stuck with this and have no idea with fixing it, therefore asking for advice.
Code is here : https://codepen.io/hela/pen/YLNVab
Thanks in advance.